# How to use apply to multiple keyword func in Racket?

Tags: racket

I meet such a question:

I want to use (send my-list-box set data) to refresh list-box%'s data on runtime. But I
can't write it like this:

```
   (apply
     send my-list-box set
     (map ....))
```

This is invalid. But I know max func can do this:

```
(apply
  max
  (map ...))
```

The only difference is "send my-list-box set" have multiple keyword, not a single keyword
func like max.

How solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`send/apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/ivaraccess.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/class-internal..rkt%29._send/apply%29%29) to apply multiple arguments to `send`:

```
(send/apply my-list-box set (map ...))
```

The `(apply send my-list-box set (map ...))` (that you were trying to use) is only invalid because `send` is a syntax (macro), not because there are multiple preceding arguments. For example, this works:

```
(apply + 1 2 3 '(4 5 6))
```

Comment: @simmone [Eli Barzilay](http://stackoverflow.com/users/128595/eli-barzilay) is a core Racket developer. You're welcome to ask any Racket question on Stack Overflow, and if nobody else can answer it, I'm pretty sure Eli can. :-) (In fact, he wrote an answer to your question; it just happened to be almost identical to mine.)

Comment: Yes, I see this avatar so often, I'm very happy to encounter all of you on stackoverflow.